# How much model name matter in injecting into a function in controller[Base on a problem]?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-6, route-model-binding

days before i was working on my homework which a problem cause me many days to fix and it was weird for me but somehow I've got that problem again which i'm pretty sure it's about how i name my model when I'm injecting it into function. Here's the full issues

Before when i was going to delete/update data with api i was using :

```
public function destroy(Event $event, EventGallery $eventGallery)
{

    $eventGallery->delete();
    return response(null,Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
}
```

And i saw nothing going to happen, then I've changed `$eventGallery` to `$gallery` then my problem solved and with this, I've seen this problem was in 2 more functions.

In my Event Model i had relation with gallery name and also it's in protected field, now there's a problem like this again, but it's not working at all, i also had `EventVideo $videos` and it wasn't working, then i changed it to `$video` and it worked.

Right now base on above information i need to know why this happen? How changing `$eventGallery or $videos` to `$gallery or $video[related with videos name in Event model and protected with videos` fix this?

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing controller code and the routes where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) concept, if your url is

has parameter

```
{eventGallery}
```

you have to use

```
EventGallery $eventGallery
```

if you want `{gallery}`

then you need to use

```
EventGallery $gallery
```

Comment: i had a clue about this, but how about $videos to $video ? in route is videos and i'm using this for spa, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/teams/natus-vincere/videos/26` it's `admin/teams/{team}/videos` - $videos wasn't working but $video worked.

Comment: @Atlas-Pio what ever parameter you are sending in route get that in method and that should work fine, for `admin/teams/{team}/videos` your parameter is `{{team}}` so you should get `$team` in your method and for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/admin/teams/natus-vincere/videos/26` what is `26`, check you route parameter name based on that you need to specify the method argument.